Locating an svg element with selenium
I am trying to automate the download process of stocks from the website below initially starting with one stock: Turkiye Sigorta (i have a subscription, i hope you can access the URL):
https://fintables.com/sirketler/TURSG/finansal-tablolar/gelir-tablosu?period=&type=&currency=usd
Inspecting the 'Excel'e Aktar' text, which is the text that needs to be clicked on to download the financials in excel, i noticed it's within an svg element.
Can you please assist with the code which is not working at the moment:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException

url = 'https://fintables.com/sirketler/TURSG/finansal-tablolar/bilanco?period=&type=&currency=usd'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

try:
    svg_element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[name()='svg']")))

    # Find the specific SVG element containing the text 'Excel'e Aktar' (with capital 'A')
    excel_button_svg = svg_element.find_element(By.XPATH, f".//*[contains(text(), \"Excel'e Aktar\")]")

    # Click the 'Excel'e Aktar' button within the SVG
    excel_button_svg.click()

except NoSuchElementException:
    print("SVG or button not found")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for SVG element to be clickable")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {str(e)}")

Thank you for your assistance and time, much appreciated! I will be trying to automate the download exercise for +550 stocks after successfully sorting this out with your help.

You state it's not working but you don't explain HOW it's not working... does it throw an error? If it does, edit your question and add the full error message, properly formatted. If there's no error, explain exactly what isn't working correctly.

The download button is actually NOT inside the SVG... it is a sibling of it. The code below works
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://fintables.com/sirketler/TURSG/finansal-tablolar/bilanco?period=&type=&currency=usd'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()=\"Excel'e Aktar\"]"))).click()

